# How do I write to the next row of a .csv file after the user has inputted values without the previous values being overwritten?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

This is my first post on stackoverflow so I apologize if I'm doing something incorrectly.

I'm creating this program where students can swipe their card and it will prompt them to type in their name. When they finish, the program will write everything to a csv file. My problem is that the entries are being overwritten by the last entry that is inputted. Is there a way for the program to write all of the entries into the csv file without being overwritten by the last entry?

This is the function that I'm using to write the entries to the csv file.

```
void firstTimeDialog::on_buttonBox_clicked(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    QFile studentLogIn("studentLogin.csv");
    QTextStream write(&studentLogIn);

    if(!studentLogIn.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "title", "studentLogIn.csv isn't open");
    }

    write << getIDNumber() << ", " << getName() << endl;
}
```

The getIDNumber() and getName() functions only return the id number of the student and the student's name.

If I were to open the csv file, I'm expecting it to show: 
(Using commas to indicate the next cell of the csv file)

> #### 12345678, John Doe
>
> #### 87654321, Frank Doe
>
> #### 01234556, Bob Doe

Instead, it shows me the last entry, which would be

> #### 01234556, Bob Doe

Comment: Hi! You've set flag as overwriting, that's why it happens =) Try `studentLogIn.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)`, that should help. Assistant says explicitly: "Note that, for file-system subclasses (e.g. QFile), this mode implies Truncate unless combined with ReadOnly, Append or NewOnly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the flag `QIODevice::Append` so that it is written to the end of the file:

```cpp
if(!studentLogIn.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Append))
```